# How to compare a long long with a double?

Tags: c++, double, long-long

<sup>(This *has* to be a duplicate, but I can't find a duplicate...)</sup>
How do I properly compare a `long long` with a `double` in C++?

Casting either to the other can cause loss of precision and possibly overflow, so I'm not sure what to do...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly:  Use a `long double` on a platform where `long double`s have a 64-bit significand.

If you want to handle platforms without such support:

I'm going to assume a `long long` is 64-bit and a `double` is the usual IEEE 64-bit `double`.

If `d >= 0x1.0p63`, then your `long long` is less than it.  If `d < -0x1.0p63`, then your `long long` is greater than it.  If `d != d`, the comparison should return `false` because `d` is NaN.  If `fabs(d) >= 0x1.0p53`, `d` represents an integer, so you can convert `d` to `long long` and do your comparison with `long long`s.  Otherwise, you can convert `ll` to `double` and do your comparison with `double`s; if any low bits are lost, they are irrelevant to the comparison.

Code (uncompiled and untested):

```
#define COMPAR(a, b) ((a) < (b) ? -1 : (a) == (b) ? 0 : 1)
int compar(long long a, double b) {
  if (b != b) return false;
  if (b >= 0x1.0p63) return -1;
  if (b < -0x1.0p63) return 1;
  if (fabs(b) >= 0x1.0p53) return COMPAR(a, (long long)b);
  else return COMPAR((double)a, b);
}
#undef COMPAR
```

Comment: Ohh, it didn't occur to me to compare with `0x1.0p63` first... great, thanks!